# Swift writing a function that takes self as an input

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have alert that is being fired from different location so I decided to make a function to be called.

```
func alertSCFlag(x: Int) {
    var alert = UIAlertController()
    switch x {
    case 1:
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Not Finished", message: "sorry but you must give the project a title and description", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    default:
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Not Finished", message: "sorry but you need to choose a type of project", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is that the self obviously isn't universal and I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass it.  Is there a way to pass self or better yet a superior way to approach the problem overall?

Comment: You need an instance of `UIViewController` to present the alert on, so add a `viewController:UIViewController` parameter to your function and then you will pass `self` as that parameter value when you call the function.

Comment: Also, passing an `Int` isn’t very Swifty. Declare an enumeration and pass an appropriate value.

Comment: And make alert a constant, specify its type and don't instantiate a new controller there. `let alert: UIAlertController`

Comment: @Paulw11 can I ask why?

Comment: Why what? Why use an enumeration instead of an Int?

Comment: @LeoDabus are you saying I should pass the alert from where it is being called?

Comment: Btw better to create that method as an extension of UIViewController

Comment: @LeoDabus that's very true, thanks

Comment: Aaron, the reason you want an `enum` rather than using an `Int` is to make it more readable. When you look at this project in six months are you going to remember that `1` means the project is missing its title or description? If you add more possible errors will you remember them? If you had an `enum`, `SCAlertReason` with a `case`, `noTitle` every time you saw `.noTitle` you would know what it means. You would also be able to pick the reason you want from autocomplete. Put the knowledge in the code, not your head.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to extend UIViewController this way you don't need to pass any view controller as parameter and self will always be a view controller. And make sure you call the view controller's present method `present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` from the main thread:

```
extension UIViewController {
   enum Message: CustomStringConvertible  {
        case missingTitle, chooseProject
        var description: String {
            let message: String
            switch self {
            case .missingTitle: message = "sorry but you must give the project a title and description"
            case .chooseProject: message = "sorry but you need to choose a type of project"
            }
            return message
        }
    }
    func alertSCFlag(title: String = "Not Finished", message: Message) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message.description, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.alertSCFlag(message: .chooseProject)
```

Comment: Since the code to create the alert is the same for both cases, it would be simpler to use the `switch` to set a `title` variable and create the alert after the `switch`.

Comment: I would add a title or message parameter to the method but the question is how to make the self available to the method