# Present a view controller from a closure

Tags: swift

I have a closure as a handler for items that are added to a UIAlertController. I receive the id value inside the closure as expected. (I don't use it in the snippet).

But the problem that I have is that I want to switch to another view controller. But I do this call inside the closure.

I get the following error:
    `Value of type '(ChooseProfile) -> () -> (ChooseProfile)' has no member 'present`'

How can I switch to another view controller from within my closure?

```
class ChooseProfile: UIViewController {
    let closure = { (id: String) in { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in        
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test") as! UIViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }}
}
```

I use this closure because of this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose a Device", message: "Which device would you like to use in this app?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        for dev in (DataSingleton.instance.getDevices())! {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: dev.getName(), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: closure(dev.getId())))
        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add a new Profile", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: nil))


        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I add the alert actions based on a list of devices. And I want to retrieve the id when I click on a device.

Comment: Where are you declaring this closure?

Comment: @vacawama I have edited my question

Comment: Is closure a property of your VC?

Comment: @vacawama I declare it like showed in the code above. So yes I think it is a property.

Comment: You show how you declared it, but not where.  Is it at the top level of your VC?

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: The problem is that you are using `self` in your closure, but that `self` doesn't refer to the instance of your VC because it hasn't been fully created yet.  Try changing your closure from `let` to `lazy var`. Also, you have a closure that creates a closure.  What does the `id` provide?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190809/swift-writing-a-function-that-takes-self-as-an-input/47191134?s=5|0.0000#47191134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using self in your closure, but that self doesn't refer to the instance of your VC because it hasn't been fully created yet.  Instead, why not pass the viewController to the closure when you call it?

```
class ChooseProfile: UIViewController {
    let closure = { (id: String, vc: UIViewController) in { [weak vc] (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in        
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test")
        vc?.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }}
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose a Device", message: "Which device would you like to use in this app?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    for dev in (DataSingleton.instance.getDevices())! {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: dev.getName(), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: closure(dev.getId(), self)))
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add a new Profile", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: nil))


    // show the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```